# using jquery how to use fadein, delay and then fadeout issue

Tags: jquery, css, dhtml

I need to make something fadeIn, then stay there for a second and then fadeOut using JQuery.

I've tried this but it dosent work for some reason???

```
$('#' + uMessage).fadeIn("fast").fadeOut("slow");  // works
$('#' + uMessage).fadeIn("fast").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");  // fails
```

any suggestions where im going wrong?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Where does it fail? Does it do anything at all?

Comment: ah, sorry, it doesnt fadeout when I add the delay..

Comment: Are you calling `.stop()` or clearing the queue in some *other* way?

Comment: `.delay` only works with jQuery 1.4 +. Could that be it?

Comment: please be so kind to accept the right answer when you've solved it?

Answer (score 14):

Your second approach should be fine actually, corresponding to the docs (http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Another approach may be to use the callback function which is called when the fadeIn has finished:

```
$('#' + uMessage).fadeIn("fast", function() { $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut("slow"); });
```

just a guess

Edit:

If you can't use the delay() method, then you could try this one:

```
$('#' + uMessage).fadeIn("fast", function() { 
  c_obj = $(this);
  window.setTimeout(function() { $(c_obj).fadeOut("slow"); }, 1000); 
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/KwWFR/

Comment: Worked for me: 

$('#message').fadeIn(function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('#message').fadeOut('slow');
  }, 2000);
});

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try using a callback as specified in the API for [FadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) function.  This will be called once the fade in is completed.

```
$('#' + uMessage).fadeIn("fast", function() {
  $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Delay with fade in fade out just doesn't work. Using a combination with queue after delay and a callback sometimes works for other situations

This ended up working for me:

```
$('#message').fadeIn(function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('#message').fadeOut('slow');
  }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the version of jQuery you use:

http://jsfiddle.net/b85hx/

This one works fine. Switch to 1.3.2 and it's broken.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery 1.4+? The delay() function was added in jQuery 1.4

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery official documentation says, that second param is not a callback, but easing style.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/#fadeIn-duration-easing-complete
http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#fadeOut-duration-easing-complete

```
$('#el').fadeOut(750,'swing',function(){
    $('#el').fadeIn();
});
```

So **just move your callback to 3rd param** and everything will work.

Comment: tried this with jquery 1.3.2 - function does not fire.

Comment: then report to jQuery, because it must fire according to docs. I bet you have issue with selector or some other place though.